# Is my pineapple dying

Tags: plant-health

[image] 
I have been growing this pineapple for about two months and recently the fruit started turning brownish. Is it dying or have a problem? What should I do?

Comment: So should I water it less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand your new plant may just be adjusting to different conditions of light. As we know pineapple requires a lot of light, as much as you can provide. On the other hand, I would be more concerned about the tips of the leaves turning brown and the way they are curled up, which indicates more of a water problem. Pineapple is a dry land bromeliad, which absorbs a lot of moisture through the leaves in the high humid conditions it requires, while at the same time having well drained roots. Think back to how you have been watering, and consider that humidity needs to be pretty high, even artificially, in the immediate area of the pineapple, and that trying to get water into the plant through the roots might cause more damage than good.